# Continue Program Execution after Catching Exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, inputmismatchexception

After catching an exception, how do I continue the execution of a Java program?

I made a program that asks a user to enter a number and it will return that number divided by a random number generated. However, if the user enters a letter like 'a', an exception will be caught.

How do I make the program continue its execution instead of terminating after it catches the exception?

```
do{                     //Begin of loop 
    try{                        //Try this code 
        System.out.println("Enter a number"); 
        double i = read.nextDouble(); //Reads user input  
        double rn = r.nextInt(10);   //Generates random number rn 
        System.out.println(i +  " divided by random number " + rn + " is " + (i/rn)); 
    }catch(InputMismatchException type_error){         //Catches error if there is a type mismatch
        //Example error: if user enters a letter instead of a double
         System.out.println("Error. You cannot divide a letter by a number!"); 
        break;  //break stops the execution of the program 
    } 

    //using a continue statement here does not work 
}while(true);       //Loop forever
```

Comment: Swap `break` with `continue`?

Comment: Swapping break with continue would terminate the loop after one entry.

Comment: Juste removing "break;" should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Continue won't help! If you use Scanner class to input the numbers, you got an infinite loop writing "Error. You cannot divide a letter by a number!" to the output.

Your code waits for a double number, but got a letter. This event triggers an exception, the code displays the error message. But the letter will remains in the scanner, so the nextInt command tries to load the same letter in the next iteration, without wait for you typing.

In the catch block, you have to empty the scanner with a read.next() command.

```
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    do {                     //Begin of loop 

        try {                        //Try this code 
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            double i = read.nextDouble(); //Reads user input  
            double rn = r.nextInt(10);   //Generates random number rn 
            System.out.println(i + " divided by random number " + rn + " is " + (i / rn));

        } catch (InputMismatchException type_error) {         //Catches error if there is a type mismatch
            //Example error: if user enters a letter instead of a double
            System.out.println("Error. You cannot divide a letter by a number!");

            // Empty the scanner before the next iteration: 
            read.next();
        }

    //using a continue statement here does not work 
    } while (true);       //Loop forever
```

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` statement will restart the loop (as opposed to the `break` statement, which terminates the loop).

As such if you replace `break;` with `continue;`, you will keep on looping after your `Exception` is caught (providing no other `Exception` is thrown but the one caught), ans the error message is displayed.

Essentially it will print `"Enter a number"` again, etc.

**Warning**

You also need to consume the `Scanner`'s next value. 
If you don't, using `continue` will loop forever with no user interaction when an error occurs.

**Example**

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    try {
        // trimmed out non-necessary stuff
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        double i = Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
        System.out.println(i);
        // changed exception caught
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException type_error) {
        System.out.println("Error. You cannot divide a letter by a number!");
        continue;
    }

} while (true);
```

**Final note**

As mentioned by [Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612858/berger), `continue` here is not even necessary because you are only printing a warning message.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate on what you mean by consume the Scanner's next value? When I remove the break statement, after it catches an exception it forever prints: Enter a number, and displays the error message without giving a chance to enter.

Comment: @MichealBingham you're welcome. See my edit: the `nextDouble` invocation will not consume the scanner's next value, only retrieve it, whereas the `nextLine` idiom will require the user to type again and return. So upon error with `nextDouble`, you'd run into an infinite loop because it keeps on failing. To fix that implies a slightly different idiom (and `Exception` handler).

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement is causing the end of the loop.

> The `break` statement has two forms: labeled and unlabeled. You saw the
>   unlabeled form in the previous discussion of the switch statement. You
>   can also use an unlabeled break to **terminate** a for, while, or do-while
>   loop

**Solution :**

Change it to `continue`.

> The `continue` statement skips the current iteration of a for, while ,
>   or do-while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement causes the loop to exit. Since you have no code in the loop after the `try`-`catch` construct, you can simply remove the `break` statement.

Note that the `Scanner` method (I assume `read` is a `Scanner`) `nextDouble()` returns the double value if the next token represents a double. If not, it throws an exception without consuming that token. So you need to ensure you consume the next value, which you can do with `read.next()`:

```
do{                     //Begin loop 

    try{                        //Try this code 
        System.out.println("Enter a number"); 
        double i = read.nextDouble(); //Reads user input  
        double rn = r.nextInt(10);   //Generates random number rn 
        System.out.println(i +  " divided by random number " + rn + " is " + (i/rn)); 


    }catch(InputMismatchException type_error){         //Catches error if there is a type mismatch
    //Example error: if user enters a letter instead of a double
         System.out.println("Error. You cannot divide " + read.next() + " by a number!"); 

    } 



} while(true);
```

Comment: When I do this, the program then forever loops and asks: Enter a number, and then Displays the error message without giving the opportunity to enter a number.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is just replace `break` with `read.nextLine();`.

`break` statement is causing the end of the loop.

`continue` will prints `Enter a number` again and again.

But `read.nextLine();`, code will asks the input again and again.

If you remove `read.nextLine();` or `continue`, code will prints Enter a number again and again.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked! But I'm not sure exactly why did that work

Comment: @MichealBingham, input token won't be consumed, so you need to consume it explicitly again. `nextLine()` will do it.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the break; from there, and everything will work fine.

Remember however to put a termination condition, i don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @Mena It is sufficient. You don't need to use continue, because it a continuous loop. It will again go and ask for input. A termination condition is required only because, it is infinite loop.